# can i develop a multiple platform project -windows/Android- entirely with a single cross-platform language?

Tags: java, c#, android, windows, cross-platform

as i'm still learning, i'm not sure what tools, frameworks, even languages i'm gonna work with..

so i'm working on a simple project that got windows side and android side.. that obviously needs at least 2 languages to get it done, but it's impossible that i can learn those languages and know how to deal with their frameworks to get the job done

so is there a language i can develop the entire project(windows & android) with, and without need to any other language no matter what or how many tools or methods im gonna use to make it work?

-note: i know java is essential for the android side, so that's the point im talking about.... "entirely"

Comment: Sorry, general software/tool questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you giving a loot at [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/), it's not like native windows but it can produce applications for Android, iOS and web with a single codebase. It's really intuitive to use and the apps built with it work really well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at React Native expect you need a Native app that you have to use Java as the core language if not give a trial to this

Answer (score 0):

I notice you've tagged this with C#. To answer your question: that. You can write Android apps in it as well via a library called Xamarin that Microsoft bought out and has integrated into the platform.